# How to release the cached memory by pss in android

Tags: android

While dumpsys meminfo,I found this:

Total RAM: 463136 kB
Free RAM: 170277 kB (48221 cached pss + 68780 cached + 53276 free)
Used RAM: 173253 kB (152085 used pss + 3160 buffers + 176 shmem + 17832 slab)
Lost RAM: 119606 kB
ZRAM: 2168 kB physical used for 2836 kB in swap (51196 kB total swap)
KSM: 4940 kB saved from shared 36 kB
6280 kB unshared; 84220 kB volatile
Tuning: 48 (large 128), oom 108462 kB, restore limit 36154 kB (low-ram)

Does the memory cached by pss(48221 byte) can be release?And how to release

Answer (score 0):

Your RAM is the memory used by your active software, meaning the operating system and the applications that are running. The only way to release memory is to close those applications that you don't need.

To answer your question it is impossible to just clear RAM without closing any applications.

More info: http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/01/process-stats-understanding-how-your.html